# XCode Project: should we put source code in separate folders for meaningful purpose

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm a Java developer, and a new comer to ios development. In learning phrase, I try to download some sample projects (include from small one to medium one) for reading how often they do work in an ios project. As I see, often, they put all source file into one folder (include header file, source file, .storyboard file, xib file ...) and I see this will make your project become messy.

So, I come here to ask a question that. Should we put source code in separate folders base on their usage, to make project less messy, right ? For example, all custom core data model class files should put into `Model` folder. All View file (such as .storyboard, .xib file ...) should put into `View` folder. All Controller file should put into `Controller` folder ...

If you often do this, please tell me your experience, how you folder your code ? And does XCode support virtual folders (that in XCode IDE you see source code in folders, but in hard drive, they're just same).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you Project you ca do any GROUPS you want to make simple and clean your project, like my screen:

[image: Right column clean project]

Is easy and simple and you have two ways:

1) in your project right click in to right column then select  **NewGroup**

[image: right click]

2) drag and drop your folder in to a column to create a folder reference:

[image: folder reference]

this only if you want integrate in your project a root with inside files PHP, HTML, ASP and more, but attention because after you distribute your app, if a people open .app file they found inside your **REFERENCE FOLDER** with all your clear code.

I think this is it ;)

Comment: thanks :) But some "special files" such as resources, images, ... should we put in different physical folder ? I have read some post that tell me we should do that.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự no the problem is you can add avery files you want inside, but for example PHP files can't read in to iOS you have call from your app to your server, images, html, xml ext you can put inside and call them inside the app, so if you want to introduce a HTML5 project in your app you can call a ULR from ObjectiveC in a web view, or create a physic folder in the project then cal index.html in a web view

Answer (score 4):

Xcode differs from Eclipse and Android Studio in maintaining a separate project-level division of resources into folders that need have no correlation whatsoever to the file system. Given that the lack of namespaces usually leads people to be very relaxed about what formally is and is not a 'package', it's a real wild west out there.

I tend to keep things organised by mental package — model, view, controller at the top level, e.g. maybe web services, persistent store under model, etc. But even then command+shift+O and type a symbol or class name is by far the easiest way to navigate a project.

Others might argue that keeping things flat is better because then you don't have to keep the file system layout in sync manually and open-by-symbol plus the class browser obviate the need for stringent organisation, presenting a hierarchical relationship without the need to get either the disk or the workspace into agreement.

Comment: thanks :D so as your recommendation, we should put those files in separate folders (include normal source files such as class, header ...) or special files (resources, images ...) ?

Comment: I tend to keep resources both on disk and in Xcode with the source files that use them if they're essentially local to the source file (NIBs being a classic though now slightly dated example) with more global assets going into a separate folder.

Answer (score 3):

You first have to make the difference between folders and groups. Folders are used to organize contents on your filesystem whereas groups are used to organize contents within your Xcode project. You can think of groups as virtual folders. I personally prefer to keep a flat structure on the filesystem and organize everything using groups. This way is slightly more straight forward to include header files and it doesn't force you to maintain both the filesystem structure and the xcode structure.

Comment: thanks :) But some "special files" such as resources, images, ... should we put in different physical folder ? I have read some post that tell me we should do that. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that's the way I do it as well, source files in a flat directory structure and the resources in their own directory, since is easier to work with them for the other team members (eg graphic designers, sound designers etc)

Answer (score 2):

Folders makes your code and its management easily, like we have packages in Java that we use to accumulate some common classes and its supporting class files.
In the same way we can use folders to manage our classes in XCode.

However its not necessary, varies from developer to developer as well as the complexity of code.

Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 2):

The approach you are discussing about is correct.

[image]

As far as folder in code is considered. If you create folder within Xcode and dividing the codes based on folders. Than all the classes will exist together on hard disk. But if you create folders within the project using finder and than adding the folder than codes will be saved to their respective folders.

Hope it will help you. Happy coding :)